# If you connect 2 car batteries in parallel and one has a low charge, how much would the low charged one draw from the other battery?

Tags: battery, charging

I'm just wondering this for the sake of understanding.

If you have a low charged battery that is connected in parallel with another battery (that is fully charged), how many amps would the low charged one typically draw from the other while it's 'charging' or equalizing with it.

Comment: You won't be seeing big currents from one lead acid battery to another, if they have equal amount of cells and no cells are shorted due to aging. 100% SOC battery may have 12.7 V and 0% 11 V (you shouldn't discharge most batteries that much). But when you put some load to that 12.7 V battery, the voltage drops very easily a few tenths. E.g. putting lights on on a car (~15 A) would drop 12.7 -> 12.1-12.4 V depending on the battery. Cranking at 100 A will drop to about 11 V and the voltage drops maybe to 10 V at 200 A.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on so many variables! Let's try to make it simple.

For starters, I'm gonna assume that the two batteries are identical, standard deep cycle automotive lead-acid, 12V, 100Ah, brand new. One of them is fully charged and the other zeroed.
The empty battery will request almost all available current on firsts seconds, which in this case, near 1100A. (assuming a zeroed battery have a standard internal resistance of 5mohm. It can vary, and you can look for the battery datasheet). And it will kill the battery due to overheating. Not a good thing.

But if you have a current regulator, you can plug it between the batteries and set the current to the standard maximum charge current (which is about 25% of the battery capacity), in this case, 25A, and let them equalize. Using this much current, the losses will be around 30% to 40%. Then, after a few hours, you gonna have the two batteries equalized with something around 40Ah of charge each.

Comment: That’s odd, when I have connected a fully charged slave battery to a flat battery I have never seen a spark fromm 1100A, even when bouncing as making the connection.

Comment: That makes sense - so best bet is to make sure that the batteries are fairly equalized before connecting them together. If we're dealing with an auxiliary battery, that would need to be topped up occasionally, I'm assuming a battery isolator would work best, as it can control the charge current - is this correct?

Comment: @SolarMike is that true? I pretty much have the opposite experience: I'll get a spark any time I even wiggle one of the connections when trying to charge a low battery from a fully charged one. Enough of a spark to seriously concern me and make me take care.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I always made sure all loads were off when connecting, minimised the chance of a spark. A friend did not and   I watched the battery explode, covered 3 cars in acid that needed respraying and we had to drag him to the washroom to get the acid out of his eyes - lucky we were in time : no damage.

Comment: @SolarMike maybe you did, but not notice. In a real world, a 100Ah battery can deliver that kind of current. But you gonna need proper cables and connections to handle that, otherwise you increase the losses in form of heat. Also, if you do the math, 1100A at 12V is something near 13200W in a perfect world, but that voltage drops a lot, lowering the power. Very much indeed, but depending of the room temperature, the battery's capacity of charge and some other variables, that current drops as the battery is being charged.

Comment: @xil3 The best is to use your best common sense. I choose specifically one scenario to answer your question very "perfect world", with a zeroed battery that has a really low impedance. But, if the battery is not really flat, I don't see any problem connecting them if you don't mind with losses. Nobody actually does! 

Comment: @Fausto I have used heavy welding cables and arc welded using larger batteries, just depends on your experience. 600A welding cable makes lovely jump leads... Much better than the rubbish you buy in car accessory shops...

Comment: @RoryAlsop I exploded a few batteries in my lab. Mostly Li-Ion. But I exploded one 14Ah lead-acid battery once. I  purposefully overcharged it with 20A and I saw it getting stuffed. Then after a few minutes, it blew. But it didn't catch fire, unlike Li-Ion. The batteries are safe, you have to mess a lot to make a real damage. What happened to SolarMike's friend is not usual, thank god! Very lucky he has such good friends to help him. At my store, that never happened. We heard stories, but nobody I know actually had this kind of accident.

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, I got what you're saying!! I'm just showing the math of a perfect world here. Also, the AIR resistance to make ARC is bigger than the internal resistance of the battery! A simple Honda Civic engine START drains about 800A from the battery at the start, and as the voltage drops, the current increases to more than 1000A (The higher my amp meter can measure). I made these tests a lot.

Comment: @SolarMike, if the flat battery is truly flat, the electrolyte will be very close to plain water, and it won't allow much current flow at all. Many modern battery chargers have a circuit to turn it off when the charging current gets too low to avoid overcharging, so when you try to charge a completely dead battery you have to fool it by connecting a small light bulb or whatever in parallel with the charger so the charger thinks its "charging".